# ruby access subhash chain using address array

Tags: ruby, hash

Lets say I have:

```
a = { b:1 , c: { d:2, e:3 } }
address = [:c, :e]
```

I *could* access that `3` with

```
a[ address[0] ][ address[1] ]
```

but this is not flexible, I want to be able to take an arbitrary address array and go through the hash for it.

Is there an elegant way to do this or do I need to write a recursive method? [RubyDoc's Fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) would be great if it accepted an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = { b:1 , c: { d:2, e:3 } }
address = [:c, :e]
address.inject(a, :[])
# => 3
```

Comment: `&` is not necessary because [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) accepts a symbol as the second parameter.

Comment: Do you know how to modify it? `address.inject(a, :[]) = 4` won't work... thanks!

Comment: @ClothSword - that would look a little awkward - something like: `address[0..-2].inject(a, :[])[address.last] = 4`

Answer (score 1):

A way using recursion:

```
def probe(h, address)
  address.size==1 ? h[address.first] : probe(h[address.first], address[1..-1])
end

h = { b:1 , c: { d:2, e:3 } }
a = [:c, :e]
probe(h,a) #=> 3
```

or, if you prefer:

```
def probe(h, address)
  begin
    probe(h[address.first], address[1..-1])
  rescue TypeError
    return h[address.first]
  end
end
```